# SharePoint 2013 list view issue

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2013

I have a List View web part in my SharePoint 2013 site that displays some documents and I wanted to change the view of this web part to show different items.  However, when I change the view, everyone else still sees the old view even though I have checked in and published the page.  I've had brand new users come to the page and I've had people clear their cache, but still they see the old view.  Personalization is not turned on.  This is only occurring for the list view web parts - other changes to other web parts are seen by different users just fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Disable the Data View Caching, there is a propety called "Enable Data View Caching".

https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/24719/list-view-caching-on-publishing-page

Comment: Ok, output caching was the issue - and a view that I needed to limit even further.  Your link helped.  Thanks.